# How to order a matrix of object

Tags: java

I'm working on an application that read a file Excel with Apache POI. I put the cells value inside a matrix of String object.

```
[title 1][title 2][title 3]
[mark]   [smith]  [34]
[simon]  [black]  [24]
```

I've been ask to allow to order the matrix according to the selected column.
How can I order a matrix of String object?

Thank you

Comment: Order then by what criteria?

Comment: By column, that are number or string

Comment: The first problem I would fix is the design: why are you putting everything inside a matrix of Strings? Why not creating a Pojo Class which represent the content of that file? Is that suitable for you? And: is the excel always made of the same columns? Need more info :)

Comment: Because this is the software I get from other developer

Comment: How about creating a normal class structure, from what i can tell, this is Employee that can have multiple fields. now you can make it implement Comparable<Employee>, and with method implementation for compareTo(Employee emp2) the list it will sort itself with sorting method.

Comment: My original question still stands, by what criteria exactly? Do you want to sort by alphabetical order or something similar to that fashion?

Comment: @Matthew alphabetical order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have only few columns you can create some comparators with a meaningful name and sort like below:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] matrix = {{"mark","smith","34"},
                         {"simon","black","24"},
                         {"foo","bar","44"}
                        };        

    Comparator<String[]> firstNameComparator  = new Comparator<String[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String[] row1, String[] row2) {
            return row1[0].compareTo(row2[0]);
        }
    };
    Comparator<String[]> lastNameComparator  = new Comparator<String[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String[] row1, String[] row2) {
            return row1[1].compareTo(row2[1]);
        }
    };
    Comparator<String[]> ageComparator  = new Comparator<String[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String[] row1, String[] row2) {
            return Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(row1[2]), Integer.parseInt(row2[2]));
        }
    };
    Arrays.sort(matrix, firstNameComparator);// pass the desired comparator
    for(String[] row:matrix){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }
}
```

or create a class that extends Comparator and pass the column index:

```
public class NewClass5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] matrix = {{"mark","smith","34"},
                             {"simon","black","24"},
                             {"foo","bar","44"}
                            }; 

        Arrays.sort(matrix, new CompareByColumn(1));// pass the desired index
        for(String[] row:matrix){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
        }
    }
    static class CompareByColumn implements Comparator {
        int columnToSort;
        CompareByColumn(int columnToSort) {
            this.columnToSort = columnToSort;
        }
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                String[] row1 = (String[]) o1;
                String[] row2 = (String[]) o2;
                return row1[columnToSort].compareTo(row2[columnToSort]);
        }
    }    
}
```

With java 8 and streams you can write it even more compactly:

```
String[][] sorted = Arrays.stream(matrix)
                          .sorted((s1,s2)->s1[1].compareTo(s2[1])) // pass the desired index
                          .toArray(String[][]::new);
for(String[] row: sorted){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
}
```

**EDIT**

Since you prefer the stream approach, I have only reworked this one. But you can use it for the other approaches as well. You can check before the comparison if the corresponding column contains numbers and make your comparison in a simple if-else either for numbers or strings.

```
    int colIndex  = 2;
    String[][] sorted = Arrays.stream(matrix).sorted((s1,s2)-> {
                            if(s1[colIndex].matches("(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)")){
                                return Double.compare(Double.parseDouble(s1[colIndex]), Double.parseDouble(s2[colIndex]));
                            }
                            else{
                                return s1[2].compareTo(s2[2]);
                            }}) 
                      .toArray(String[][]::new);

    for(String[] row: sorted){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }
```

Used this `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` regex to match both integer and floating point numbers.

Comment: I like the Java 8 one-line solution, works like a charm.

Comment: Really thank you for your big help.
The problem is that inside the matrix made of Strings, a string can actually contains a number  (1, 45.48, ecc.) and I should sort that "numbers" as well.
I'm pretty confused

Comment: @MDP Edited my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

First of all thank you for this question, it proved to be quite a mental challenge to visualize and implement this solution. I hope the following solution is what you wanted.

I've written a method that will sort the matrix for you. The method takes a `String` matrix as an argument and returns a new `String` matrix with each column sorted by alphabetic older. The sorting is done independent of other columns so each column is sorted without external context.

Unfortunately it doesn't exclude the titles from the sorting process so if you need that to happen please let me know and I will do my best to implement that.

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String str) {
    return str.matches("^[0-9]+$");
}

public static String[][] sortMatrix(String[][] matrix)
{
    int matrixLength = matrix[0].length;

    String[][] sortedMatrix = new String[matrixLength][];
    java.util.List<String[]> columns = new java.util.ArrayList<>();

    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < matrixLength; i1++)
    {
        String[] column = new String[matrixLength];
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < matrixLength; i2++) {
            column[i2] = matrix[i2][i1];
        }
        columns.add(column);
    }

    // First sort the column before proceeding
    columns.forEach(column -> Arrays.sort(column, new Comparator<String>()
    {
        public int compare(String s1, String s2)
        {
            boolean i1 = isNumeric(s1);
            boolean i2 = isNumeric(s2);

            if (i1 && i2) {
                return Integer.valueOf(s1).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(s2));
            }
            else if (!i1) {
                return 1;
            }
            else return -1;
        }
    }));

    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < columns.size(); i1++)
    {
        String[] row = new String[matrixLength];
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < matrixLength; i2++) {
            row[i2] = columns.get(i2)[i1];
        }
        sortedMatrix[i1] = row;
    }
    return sortedMatrix;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String[][] matrix = new String[3][] ;
    matrix[0] = new String[] { "title 1", "title 2", "title 3" };
    matrix[1] = new String[] { "simon", "1", "10" };
    matrix[2] = new String[] { "mark", "35", "2" };

    matrix = sortMatrix(matrix);
    for (String[] row : matrix) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Implemented a custom comparator that takes number into account.

Comment: Really thank you for your big help. The problem is that inside the matrix made of Strings, a string can actually contains a number (1, 45.48, ecc.) and I should sort that "numbers" as well. I'm pretty confused

Comment: I've updated my answer so that the implementation is sensitive to numbers. Everything should work now. Let me know if there are any hickups in code execution.